# Jframe. adding 2 Jpanel components in one frame. Doesnt work

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

Problem : i'm trying to add a 2nd Jpanel in my frame but when i add this latter, it overwrites the previous one. The purpose is to have 2 components (Jpanels) in the same frame but it seem to accept only one but not both. The order of appearence should be in one column and two rows: 
1: Enter name:
2: TextField

```
   import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class Money2 extends JFrame {
    public Money2() {

        // setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Enter name:"));
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // p2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        p2.add(new JTextField(8));

        add(p1); // add to Jframe
        add(p2);
    }

    /** Main method */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Money2 frame = new Money2();
        frame.setTitle("Money Converter App");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(350, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the p1.add(p2); but it keeps showing both in one row. Should be in 2 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both panels cannot occupy the same location in a `BorderLayout`. You could place panel `p1` at a different location:

```
add(p1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

Comment: add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout() );
  frame.add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

Comment: The above answer is equivalent. You don't need to call `frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());` as this is the default layout for `JFrame`.